# Фото уезжает за экран php

Tags: php, html, css

Всем привет. Пишу сайт впервые, а потому не слишком опытен в этом! Всё, вроде, работает идеально, но всё же хоть какая-то фигня да вылезет :(

Делаю на php скрипт, который достаёт данные из бд и на их основе создаёт много блоков по шаблону. Вверху картинка, под ней текст. Они должны быть ссылкой на страницу. Вроде всё нормально, но после обновления страницы картинка пропадает... И появляется она только, если нажать Ctrl+F5 (Chrome). Что я выяснил:

1. Проблема именно с тегом  и именно с картинкой, ведь текст не пропадает.
2. Картинка не исчезает полностью - если изменить у всех блоков overflow: hidden на visible, то небольшая часть фото будет выпирать слева за самим экраном пк.
3. Поигравшись со стилями понял, что если убрать justify-content: center, то фото не пропадает и всё нормально, только вот мне нужно, чтобы картинка была по центру блока.
4. Ссылка уходит вместе с картинкой, то есть перейти по ней нельзя.
5. Скопировал нужный фрагмент кода в отдельный php файл и прицепил тот же css. Фото теперь и вовсе не появляется! Но по ссылке (нажав на пустое место, где должна быть картинка) перейти можно...
6. От фото, переменных и адресов проблема не зависит.

Код с отдельного файла:

```
<body>
    <div class="block1">
        <?php
            echo '
            <div class="block2">
                <div class="block-img">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/main.jpg" width="auto" height="100%" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>';
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Фрагмент CSS, который хоть как то относится к нужным блокам:

```
/* --------------- reset.css --------------- */
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, em, img, strong, sub, sup, b, u, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0; /* обнуляем отступы и убираем бордюры */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* приводим все к одной базовой линии */
    background: transparent; /* чтобы не проскакивали левые фоны, установленные по умолчанию */
    font-size: 100%; /* размер шрифта всем одинаковый */
}

a { /* ссылка не в общем списке чтобы не сбрасывать outline по умолчанию */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

table { /* устраняем отступы между ячейками таблицы */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td, td img {
    vertical-align: top; /* возвращаем привычное вертикальное выравнивание */
}

input, select, button, textarea {
    margin: 0; /* убираем отступы по умолчанию для элементов форм (в частности для checkbox и radio) */
    font-size: 100%; /* делаем размер шрифтов везде одинаковым */
}

    input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
        padding: 0; /* убираем внутренние отступы для текстовых полей */
    }

    input[type="checkbox"] { /* вертикальное выравнивание чекбоксов и радиобатонов относительно меток */
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    input[type="radio"] {
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }

sub {
    vertical-align: sub;
    font-size: smaller;
}

sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: smaller;
}
/* --------------- /reset.css --------------- */

/* --------------- базовые настройки ---------*/
html {
    overflow-y: scroll; /* всегда показываем вертикальную полосу прокрутки  */
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font: 14px Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif; /* используем безопасные шрифтовые CSS стеки */
}

input, select, button, textarea {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif; /* чтобы шрифт был такой же как и везде */
}

    label, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], button {
        cursor: pointer; /* курсор в виде руки для всех кликабельных элементов форм */
    }

a, a:visited { /* порядок правил для ссылок имеет значение */
    color: #287fc3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:hover {
        color: #287fc3;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:focus, a:active {
        color: #287fc3;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

/* --------------- /базовые настройки ---------*/


body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
}

html {
    height: 100%
}
.block1 {
    margin: auto;
    /*border: 4px double;*/
    width: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.block2 {
    width: 32%;
    border: 1px double;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block-img {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dotted;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Планируемый макет страницы:
[image: Планируемый макет страницы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было бы хорошо увидеть ссылку на то как это на сайте планируется. Так как не понятно что же вы хотите получить. Если разметку из 3-х колонок в каждой из которых картинка и текст, то у вас лучше бы сделать иначе разметку и сами стили.

Например:

```css
.container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -12px;
}

.block__item {
    width: 33.3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.block__plate {
    border: 1px double;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.block__img {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dotted;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.block__img img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
      <div class="block__item">
          <a href="" class="block__plate">
              <span href="" class="block__img">
                  <img src="http://frontendie.ru/jobs/botstrapslider/img/1480439597175676615.jpg" />
              </span>
              <span>Item 1</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="block__item">
          <a href="" class="block__plate">
              <span href="" class="block__img">
                  <img src="http://frontendie.ru/jobs/botstrapslider/img/1480439597175676615.jpg" />
              </span>
              <span>Item 2</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="block__item">
          <a href="" class="block__plate">
              <span href="" class="block__img">
                  <img src="http://frontendie.ru/jobs/botstrapslider/img/1480439597175676615.jpg" />
              </span>
              <span>Item 3</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="block__item">
          <a href="" class="block__plate">
              <span href="" class="block__img">
                  <img src="http://frontendie.ru/jobs/botstrapslider/img/1480439597175676615.jpg" />
              </span>
              <span>Item 4</span>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: > `то как это на сайте планируется.`
Добавил фото ожидаемого макета страницы.

Comment: Отредактировал код. Это по сути стандартная сетка в несколько колонок. В принципе можно сделать и с меньшим количеством тэгов, но на мой взгляд не принципиально.